# Only Initials with multiple authors IEEEtran Bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, ieeetran, sorting

I am using a bib file to create my bibliography and then i recall it like this:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{biblio}
\nocite{*}
```

I am not using the `\usepackage{biblatex}` since it gives me an error then while compiling.
There are some problems with this code:

1. If the article cited has more than 3 authors the others are displayed just with the initials of their name and surname
   [image]
2. I would like to have the bibliography sorted by appearance on the main text, but it does not work like that now.
3. Everytime I have to compile i have to delete the .bbl file otherwise the changes in the .bib file are do not appear in the bibliography.

I am really struggling with these, i do not know ho to solve them.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: Probably `biblatex` is right and something is wrong with your bib entry.

Comment: Please post the actual entries 2 and 3. There may be something strange going on in the `author` fields of these two entries.

Comment: Sorry i did not reply to any of your messages (i thought that i will recive a reminder on my email whenevere i got an answer but it turns out I was wrong). I got them wrong totally, i had no idea on the use of , and and in with bibtex, my fault!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you haven't posted the actual bib entries, it's not possible to be entirely certain in diagnosing what's going on. My strong suspicion, though, is that you have *too many commas* in the `author` fields of the entries numbered `2` and `3` in your example. In an `author` field, you must use the keyword `and` to separate authors. Use commas only if you need (or wish) to place the author's surname before the given name. In short: Don't overuse (and especially don't mis-use) commas in `author` fields. (By the way, if my suspicion is correct, BibTeX should have generated a few error messages -- which you either didn't notice or chose to ignore.)

The following code compiles fine (entries in BibTeX format obtained directly from the respective journals' websites; note that it's necessary to encase `MV` in curly braces to prevent BibTeX from converting the two letters to lowercase):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,url}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Junginger:10, 
author = {F. Junginger and A. Sell and O. Schubert and B. Mayer and D. Brida and M. Marangoni and G. Cerullo and A. Leitenstorfer and R. Huber}, 
journal = {Optics Letters}, 
number = {15}, 
pages = {2645--2647}, 
publisher = {OSA},
title = {Single-cycle multiterahertz transients with peak fields above 10 {MV}/cm}, 
volume = {35}, 
month = {Aug},
year = {2010},
url = {http://ol.osa.org/abstract.cfm?URI=ol-35-15-2645},
doi = {10.1364/OL.35.002645},
}
@article{LPOR:LPOR201000013,
author = {Cerullo, G. and Baltu{\v s}ka, A. and M{\"u}cke, O.D. and Vozzi, C.},
title = {Few-optical-cycle light pulses with passive carrier-envelope phase stabilization},
journal = {Laser \& Photonics Reviews},
volume = {5},
number = {3},
publisher = {WILEY-VCH Verlag},
issn = {1863-8899},
url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/lpor.201000013},
doi = {10.1002/lpor.201000013},
pages = {323--351},
year = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Prompted by @percusse's comment, I tried to figure out *which combination* of replacing `and` with `,` would generate the output that's shown in your screenshot. After some experimenting, I found that

```
author = {F. Junginger, A. Sell, O. Schubert, B. Mayer, D. Brida, M. Marangoni, 
   G. Cerullo, A. Leitenstorfer, and R. Huber},
```

will generate

> O. S. B. M. D. B. M. M. G. C. A. L. F. Junginger, A. Sell and R. Huber

while

```
author = {Giulio Cerullo, Andrius Baltu{\v s}ka, O. M{\"u}cke, and C. Vozzi},
```

will generate

> O. M. Giulio Cerullo, Andrius Baltuska and C. Vozzi

Not a perfect match, but pretty close, right? :-) By the way, BibTeX throws quite a few error messages on this sort of input, mainly about "too many commas" having been encountered. (Somewhat surprisingly, despite these error messages BibTeX still manages to produce a bbl file that gives rise to the output shown above.) Do pay attention to such error messages.

To sum up: Use `and` as the keyword to separate authors in the `author` field.

Comment: Can you also replicate this with a lot of commas?

Comment: Ah my bad. I meant if you could put the wrong input leading to a lot of initals instead of the proper output and biblatex giving the mentioned error.

Comment: @percusse - I've posted an addendum to implement your suggestion for a search for the actual input in the OP's bib file. I've come pretty close, I think...

Comment: Sorry i did not reply to any of your messages (i thought that i will recive a reminder on my email whenevere i got an answer but it turns out I was wrong). I got them wrong totally, i had no idea on the use of , and and in with bibtex, my fault!

Comment: Since you are so into this i will also reveal the real orrid first version of one of the two: @ARTICLE{Lei,
  author =       {F. Junginger, A. Sell, O. Schubert, B. Mayer, D. Brida, M. Marangoni, G. Cerullo, A. Leitenstorfer, and R. Huber},
  title =        {Single-cycle multiterahertz transients with peak fields above 10 MV/cm},
  journal =      {OPTICS LETTERS},
  month =        {August},
  year =         {2010}
  volume =  {35}
  number =   {15}
}

Comment: @Lucamiz01 - Thanks for clearing up this last piece of uncertainty. :-) I honestly wasn't going to post the addendum, but percusse somehow got me into it...